# If $P \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$ is abelian, then $G$ has normal $p$-complement if $P \le H$ and $H$ has one and controls $p$-transfer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, and denote by $A^p(G)$ the smallest normal subgroup such that $G / A^p(G)$ is an abelian $p$-group. Suppose $P \le H \le G$ for a fixed Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$. We say that $H$ controls $p$-transfer if $A^p(H) = H \cap A^p(G)$.

Now suppose $P \in \mbox{Syl}_p(G)$ is abelian, and $P \le H \le G$ is such that $H$ controls $p$-transfer in $G$. Show that if $H$ has a normal $p$-complement, then $G$ has a normal $p$-complement.

How to show this? If $H = PK, P \cap K$ with $K$ normal, then $P \cong H / K$, hence $H \cap A^p(G) = A^p(H) \le K$ with the assumption that $P$ is abelian; but how to proceed further?

Comment: So $A^p(H)=K$ and $|H/A^p(H)|=|P|$, but $H/A^p(H) \cong A^p(H)G/A^p(G)$ so $|G/A^p(G)|$ is divisible by $|P|$, which is only possible if $A^p(G)$ is a normal $p$-complement of $G$·

Comment: You mean $H / A^p(H) \cong HA^p(G) / A^p(G)$ and $G = PA^p(G) \le HA^p(G)$ as $A^p(G)$ has $p$-power index; not $H/A^p(G) \cong A^p(H)G / A^p(G)$, or?

Comment: Yes I meant $A^p(G)H/A^p(G)$, not $A^p(H)G/A^p(G)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you; and let me add that $A^p(H) = K$ because $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, for $|G : A^p(G)| = |G : K||K : A^p(G)|$ and $|G : K|$ already has the highest possible $p$-power we have $|K : A^p(G)| = 1$.

Comment: The problem with that is that $K \le A^p(G)$ but they are not necesarily equal ($K=A^p(H) = A^p(G) \cap H$), and if they are unequal then $|K:A^p(G)|$ does not make sense.

Comment: Oh yes thank you, that must be formulated in $H$, so $P$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup in $H$ and $|H : A^p(H)| = |H : K||K : A^p(H)|$ which implies $|K : A^p(H)| = 1$.